# x-editable force data sending

Tags: jquery, x-editable

I've got a select with two choices that doesn't update the selected value after I send request. Because the value stays, I cannot send the next change, because it thinks it's the original choice.

I've even updated the selected field manually, but it still doesn't recognize as a changed value, so it doesn't send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option for x-editable since version 1.2 called `savenochange`.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.img-thumbnail').editable({savenochange: true});
});
```

Documentation: [X-Editable Options](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#editable)